# How to implement a kafka retry policy with publishing failed messages to a Dead Letter Topic in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, polly, retry-logic

I am searching on the internet to find a code example in .NET for implementing a kafka retry policy with publishing failed messages to a Dead Letter Topic (DLT/DLQ), but I can't find an example. Does someone has some tips or links for me?

Comment: Could you please provide more information to be able to help you, like: Are you planning to use your producer in sync or in async fashion? What is your planned `acks` value? What's your problem with the [built-in retry mechanism](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_retries)? How many times do you want to issue retries before falling back to DLQ?